# Is it correct to say "don't let the door loose from the magnet"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

[image]

Look at these above pictures!

The door in my room is kept from moving freely with a magnet on the wall. It is important to keep it sticking to the magnet all the time because strong winds might slam the door shut and hut people if they happen to put their hands on the door frame.

I found this structure in the dictionary

> **[let somebody/something loose](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/loose_1?q=let%20loose)**:  ​to free somebody/something from whatever holds them/it in place
>
> *She let her hair loose and it fell around her shoulders.*
>
> *Who's let the dog loose?*

Can I say "**don't let the door loose from the magnet because it might be blown shut by the wind and hurt you**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Definition of let loose
> 1 : to allow (someone or something) to move or go freely

Source: Meriam-Webster

In this case, I would say it‘s completely fine to say that. You‘re letting the **door move freely away from the magnet**, so it would be appropriate to say that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit odd. The door isn't getting loose. I'd understand that to mean either the hinges are wobbling or the door is running around outside (!)

I'd reverse the negation:

> Make sure the door stays open (on the magnet).

In context, you probably don't need to mention the magnet, because the person already knows about it.